# h2 odbc dsn less connection string

Tags: odbc, h2

I successfully created a DSN connection to a h2 ciphered database
with this database string /icp/data/db/db;CIPHER=AES

It would be nice to be able to use a DSN less connection. 
This is a NOT working example:

```
Driver={PostgreSQL Unicode};Database=/data/db;CIPHER=AES;port=1602;Server=srv01;
                                             ^
```

This obviously does not work. I need at least to escape the semicolon in the database portion.
I've tried many combination (braces, single quote, double quote) without any success.

The same string without CIPHER=AES does work for an not encrypted db.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not my area, but this suggests, password needs to be in the connection string. http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I cannot find any reference of what you say in  features.html page. To build my knowledge, aside others, I've used the docs here http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html?highlight=cipher&search=CIPHER#file_encryption and http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html?highlight=cipher&search=CIPHER#database_file_locking